# Is the postSave hook a supported hook?

Tags: hooks

This is different than the post hook, which is officially documented. The only real reference to the postSave hook I can find is [CRM-7850](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-7850), so I'm just wondering if it's supported or if it might disappear in future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the code and that issue, the hook exists and someone just forgot to add it to the wiki. Here, I've just added it:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_postSave_table_name

Answer (score 1):

If it is not officially documented I would guess the hook is there until it disappears :-)